# Javafx how can I insert data to tableview

Tags: javafx, insert, tableview, scenebuilder

I have a question with javafx. I have a project that have operation with a bib file. I face a problem when I want to insert a class data(Entry) to table view. But it still empty in tableview. The operation is type a name and search from bib file, then show the result on Table view. 
Thanks
[The gui image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBmZP.png)

I have a class

> ```
> public class Entry implements Comparable<Entry>{
>   public static final int ignoreOrder=-1;
>   public static final int OrderByName=0;
>   public static final int OrderByTitle=1;
>   public static final int OrderByYear=2;
>   private String name;
>   private String title="";
>   private String year="0";
>   private int order=OrderByName;
>
>   public int getOrder() {
>       return order;
>   }
>   public void setOrder(int order) {
>       this.order = order;
>   }
>   public Entry(String name){
>       this.name=name;
>   }
>   public String getName() {
>       return name;
>   }
>
>   public void setName(String name) {
>       this.name = name;
>   }
>
>   public String getTitle() {
>       return title;
>   }
>   public void setTitle(String title) {
>
>       this.title = title;
>   }
>   public String getYear() {
>       return year;
>   }
>   public void setYear(String year) {
>       this.year = year;
>   }
> }
> ```

Fill the tableview, but it still empty.

```
@FXML
private TableView<Entry> table_id;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Entry, String> Col_BKey;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Entry, String> Col_counts;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Entry, String> Col_EntryType;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Entry, String> Col_Title;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Entry, String> Col_Year;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Entry, String> Col_Booktitle;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Entry, String> Col_Author;




public void loadFile(ActionEvent event){
        int orderModel=0;
        if(title_radio.isSelected()){
            orderModel=1;
        }else if(year_radio.isSelected()){
            orderModel=2;
        }
        ReadingProcessor readingProcessor=new ReadingProcessor(new OrderedLinkedList(orderModel));
        entryList=readingProcessor.read(filePath);
    }

    public void SelectOKAction(ActionEvent event) {

        String searchStr=select_text.getText();
        if(searchStr==null||searchStr.trim().equals("")){
            AlertBox.display("Wrong", "Please enter entry's name");
            return;
        }
        Entry entry=entryList.search(searchStr);
        if(entry==null){//NOT FOOUND
            AlertBox.display("Wrong", "Entry not exists!");
        }

        ObservableList<Entry> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(entry);
        table_id.setItems(list);

    }
```

Comment: The code you showed just creates an empty list and sets it as the backing list for the table. Where are you actually creating the data and adding it to the list?

Comment: I edited my code of question. I read the bib file and type a name in text to search a entry from file. I want to insert this entry into tableview, but I do not know how. Thanks @James_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing missing is `setCellValueFactory`

If you can change all your fields from `String` into `SimpleStringProperty` for example `private String title;` into `private SimpleStringProperty title` then you can simply add

```
Col_Title.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Row, String>("title"));
```

otherwise you have to lookup for a more complex `setCellValueFactory`